# Resetting Specific Form Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, mobile, field

Ive found a lot of info on the web about resetting a form. But havent been able to find much on resetting specific form fields.

Ive got a collapsable set (jquery mobile) which shows and hides part of the form, And I want it so when the user clicks on the header for the set it resets the part its hiding.

For example, if the user clicks on the header "Building / Business" it resets the fields in the 3 fields under "Street".

Heres a fiddle to help explain my question. http://jsfiddle.net/CXc93/

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: can u include some sample of what u really trying to do....You can use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry manoj, I will remember to add one from now on :)   Thanks.    http://jsfiddle.net/CXc93/

Answer (score -1):

What about something like below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          var div1;
          var div2;
          function resetter() {
            div1 = document.getElementById('dv1').innerHTML;
            div2 = document.getElementById('dv2').innerHTML;
          }
          window.onload = resetter;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body >
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" onclick="document.getElementById('dv1').innerHTML = div1" /> Div1<br />
            <div id="dv1">
                <input type="text" value=""/><br/>
                <input type="text" value=""/><br/>
            </div>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" onclick="document.getElementById('dv2').innerHTML = div2" /> Div2
            <div id="dv2">
                <input type="text" value=""/><br/>
                <input type="text" value=""/><br/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```